# Matlab code to apply conversion to every file in a folder

Tags: matlab

I have the following snippet to convert a `.wav` input to ascii `.txt` output.
How can I modify this code to convert every `.wav` file in a given directory and then output each `.txt` file to match the input filenames, which are each unique?

```
[data, fs] = audioread('waves/sampleInput.wav');
save 'sampleOutput.txt' data -ASCII
```

Comment: thank you, ill accept the answer because it's correct, just not quite working for me as of yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to a question like this is the `dir` [command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dir.html). You could try to use it in a construct like this:

```
dir_in = 'myfolder'; % set directory

filelist = dir(fullfile(dir_in, '*.wav')); % get file list

for i = 1 : length(filelist); % iterate over files in dir
    filename = filelist(i).name;
    disp(['Processing ' num2str(i) '/' num2str(length(filelist)) ': ' filename])
    [data, fs] = audioread(fullfile(dir_in,filename)); % Do your stuff for every file
    save(['sampleOutput_' filename(1:end-4) '.txt'],'data','-ascii') % add filename to output filename, but without '.wav'
end
```

The ouput will be in the current working directory I believe.

**Note:** I think it is good practice to use `fullfile` to build your paths, since this will automatically choose the correct file separator character  (Windows:`\` vs. UNIX:`/`), which means that this code is portable.

Comment: The code looks good, thank you! However, I am not getting any output.

Comment: You mean there's a problem with writing to .txt?

Comment: Essentially, yes.

Comment: I think from `audioread` you get a matrix/vector of doubles, so I think writing them to file should work. Otherwise you can try to save it using `writematrix` which saves also as text/csv file.

Comment: The issue is contained within 'save' ... i made a few changes and the program began iterating while overwriting the same file over and over again. Then a made a few more changes and now I can't replicate.

Comment: It can't be overwriting the same file if you use my code. But maybe you could post another question with more background. But keep in mind, I (and also other users) probably don't have test .wav files if thats the issue.

Comment: Thanks again! This resolved the issue: "save(['sampleOutput_' filename(1:end-4) '.txt'],'data','-ASCII')"